# How do I get created date of a custom list item?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, jsom

I am looping through my list and would like to output the created date insted of ID in a div. Is it possible?

```
while (Enumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enumerator.get_current();

    lstString += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("ID");
}

$("#items").html(lstString);
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? You must be using `JSOM` Correct?

Comment: You can update your question with code, rather than posting as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `JSOM`. The created date of a list item is stored in SharePoint's OOB field `Created`

Considering you have written the function to query list, this is the success call back function where we get values of an item.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var CreatedDate = oListItem.get_item('Created');

    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I mostly get list item values like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {    
            // Rest Call
            var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('News')/items"; // My list is called News

                $.ajax({
                    url: requestUri,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                            var created = item.Created;

                            document.getElementById("head0").innerHTML = created;

                        })
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error getting items");
                    }                     
                });   

        });
</script>

<!-- News -->
    <div class="col-md-9">
            <div id="head0"></div>
    </div>
<!-- /News -->
```

If this helps you, please give it a "vote up" or mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of ID i would like to get created date of a list item.I dont know if it is possible.

```
while (Enumerator.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enumerator.get_current();

    lstString += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("ID");
}

$("#items").html(lstString);
```

}